# List of Individuals where Sum over a period of time equals zero

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return a list of MID's (Merchant ID Numbers) who have a total transaction count of zero over the past six months (in context, the MID list where TRANSACTIONS = 0 over the last six months) but have opened greater than 6 months ago.

With my current query I'm finding that some of these individuals have zero transactions in the most recent month, but their total over the last 6 months is greater than zero.

I think the issue can be found somewhere around the WHERE statement, but I'm not sure how to correct this.

```
SELECT MERCHANTS.MID, MERCHANTS.DBA_NAME, MERCHANTS.OPEN_DATE, SUM(TRANSACTIONS) as 'Transactions Last 6 Months'

  FROM [RESIDUAL_STAGE].[dbo].[BI_DATA_MAP_201906]
  INNER JOIN MERCHANTS ON BI_DATA_MAP_201906.MID = MERCHANTS.MID
  INNER JOIN LK_BI_LEAD_SOURCE ON MERCHANTS.BI_LEAD_SOURCE = LK_BI_LEAD_SOURCE.LBLS_ROW_ID
  INNER JOIN LK_BI_PORTFOLIO ON MERCHANTS.BI_PORTFOLIO = LK_BI_PORTFOLIO.LBPORT_ROW_ID
  INNER JOIN LK_BI_PROCESSOR ON MERCHANTS.BI_PROCESSOR = LK_BI_PROCESSOR.LBP_ROW_ID
  INNER JOIN LK_BI_SALES_AGENT ON MERCHANTS.BI_SALES_AGENT = LK_BI_SALES_AGENT.LBSA_ROW_ID
  INNER JOIN LK_BI_SALES_CHANNEL ON MERCHANTS.BI_SALES_CHANNEL = LK_BI_SALES_CHANNEL.LBSC_ROW_ID

  WHERE LK_BI_SALES_CHANNEL.LK_BI_SALES_CHANNEL_DESC = 'Beacon'
  AND
  datediff(month, RESIDUAL_PERIOD, getdate()) <= 6
  AND
  TRANSACTIONS = 0
  AND
  datediff(month, MERCHANTS.OPEN_DATE, getdate()) > 6

  GROUP BY MERCHANTS.MID, MERCHANTS.DBA_NAME, MERCHANTS.OPEN_DATE

  ORDER BY MERCHANTS.DBA_NAME asc
```

Some Context:

- MERCHANTS.MID = Merchant ID numbers = individuals
- MERCHANTS.OPEN_DATE = Date of when the MID opened
- RESIDUAL_PERIOD = Date / Period of Transactions = Time measure that I want the 6 months of transactions to equal 0

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.  Well, the question makes sense. What does the query have to do with anything?  You are asking about individuals.  There are no individuals in the query.  You are asking about a single 'transaction date".  I see neither transactions nor a clear date in the query.  Also tag with a database.

Comment: I apologize; I'll add context to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conditions over aggregations (sum, avg, etc.), you should use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` keyword. So remove this from your `WHERE` condition:

```
TRANSACTIONS = 0
```

And replace it by (after your where condition):

```
HAVING SUM(TRANSACTIONS) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. This was especially helpful because of the info about the HAVING and WHERE keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the sum of transactions to be zero?  See if this works:

```
SELECT MERCHANTS.MID, MERCHANTS.DBA_NAME, MERCHANTS.OPEN_DATE,
   SUM(TRANSACTIONS) as Transactions_Last_6_Months
FROM [RESIDUAL_STAGE].[dbo].[BI_DATA_MAP_201906]
INNER JOIN MERCHANTS ON BI_DATA_MAP_201906.MID = MERCHANTS.MID
INNER JOIN LK_BI_LEAD_SOURCE ON MERCHANTS.BI_LEAD_SOURCE = LK_BI_LEAD_SOURCE.LBLS_ROW_ID
INNER JOIN LK_BI_PORTFOLIO ON MERCHANTS.BI_PORTFOLIO = LK_BI_PORTFOLIO.LBPORT_ROW_ID
INNER JOIN LK_BI_PROCESSOR ON MERCHANTS.BI_PROCESSOR = LK_BI_PROCESSOR.LBP_ROW_ID
INNER JOIN LK_BI_SALES_AGENT ON MERCHANTS.BI_SALES_AGENT = LK_BI_SALES_AGENT.LBSA_ROW_ID
INNER JOIN LK_BI_SALES_CHANNEL ON MERCHANTS.BI_SALES_CHANNEL = LK_BI_SALES_CHANNEL.LBSC_ROW_ID
WHERE LK_BI_SALES_CHANNEL.LK_BI_SALES_CHANNEL_DESC = 'Beacon'
   AND datediff(month, RESIDUAL_PERIOD, getdate()) <= 6
   AND datediff(month, MERCHANTS.OPEN_DATE, getdate()) > 6
GROUP BY MERCHANTS.MID, MERCHANTS.DBA_NAME, MERCHANTS.OPEN_DATE
HAVING SUM(TRANSACTIONS) = 0
ORDER BY MERCHANTS.DBA_NAME asc
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to return a list of individuals who have a total transaction count of zero over the past six months (in context, the MID list where TRANSACTIONS = 0 over the last six months).

I am going to ignore your query.

The basic idea is:

```
select t.individual_id
from transactions t
group by t.individual_id
having max(t.transaction_date) < current_date - interval '6 month';
```

This uses SQL standard syntax.  Date functions are likely to be different on your database.